# Can I have Web Service and a WebSite on different server with the same domain?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, http, iis

Can I have Web Service and WebSite on different server with the same domain?

Example

mysite.com (configured on IIS 7) - Server 1 EUA

mysite.com/mywebservice (configured on IIS 7) - Server 2 Australia

Can I?

Comment: Yes, use service reference in your project..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can, but you have to use load balancer. You can use build in in IIS ([more on MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj129384.aspx)) or use something else like: apache, hardware solution, etc.

You can set only redirect on mysite.com/mywebservice but you webservice client must support it.

Second option is to use www.mysite.com and  mywebservice.mysite.com and set it up on DNS.

Answer (score 0):

you can't, but you can have

- mysite.com - service 1
- mywebservice.mysite.com - service 2